# compare two sql query without executing

Tags: sql, node.js

I am creating a exam app. In this app, there is a section for sql queries, where user will be given a scenario and he has to write a sql query for it in given textbox. Now this query will go to backend and the user written query and correct query for that scenario will be compared and result of it will be send to user.

Now, I am confused about how will I compare both the queries(i.e user written query and correct query). I don't want to execute both the queries because it will take time and hinder the performance of website. Also, for particular scenario , there can be different queries which will produce the same result.

The basic example of it is :

User written query: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE age < 30 AND age > 18`

Correct query: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE age > 18 AND age < 30`

As both query will produce the same output but they are different.
So, my function should return me true.
It will be a nodejs function which will take both the queries as parameter and return either true or false.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To do this, you would have to implement a full RDBMS engine in a Node.js function. Seems like that won't be any better for performance than executing the queries. In fact, quite a lot worse. And it will take you a few decades to write it in Node.js.

Comment: Seems like a tough challenge, how do you determin "correct" when there are usually many equivalent ways to write the same query; In your example the user query could supply specific column names as the only difference and i'd argue it was even more correct.

Comment: Maybe not full RDBMS engine, but you'll need to parse queries, build join forest, build conditions tree, and compare results of this parsing for two queries. And it's not talking about comparing with `age between 19 and 29`, `trunc(age) in (18,19, ... , 29)` and so on.

Comment: A quick Google search threw up a [source](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse544/13sp/lectures/lecture16-conjunctive-queries.pdf) that claims static equivalence analysis of relational queries is undecidable.

Comment: This is [literally impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) in general. You can only approximate and either reject some correct solutions or accept some incorrect solutions. The typical approach is to run queries against some small databases and check the result. No need to have even hundreds of rows, tens should be sufficient. All correct solutions are accepted, but some incorrect may be accidentally accepted as well.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a technique called Query Normalization. In which the SQL queries are converted into Canonical form ( form obtained by ignoring non-semantic differences like white spaces , ordering of clauses) such that the normalized form of identical queries would be same.

Below is the example for query normalization using Node JS where in it requires  'sql-parse' module.

```
const sqlparser = require('sql-parse');

function normalizeQuery(query) {
  const ast = sqlparser.parse(query);
  // Traverse the AST and modify it to normalize the query
  // For example, reorder WHERE clauses, sort column lists, etc.
  // Then generate the normalized SQL from the modified AST
  return sqlparser.stringify(ast);
}

function compareQueries(query1, query2) {
  const normalized1 = normalizeQuery(query1);
  const normalized2 = normalizeQuery(query2);
  return normalized1 === normalized2;
}
```

Comment: This technique will understand that the OP's example queries are equivalent to `SELECT * FROM users WHERE age = 19 UNION SELECT * FROM users WHERE age = 20 UNION ... `?